# Replacing Activator.CreateInstance with a compiled lambda

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm trying to replace a call to Activator.CreateInstance(string, string) with a compiled lambda.

I'm seen plenty of samples here or on the web but the type is always known at compiled time. In my cas it is not, the calling code and the type are located in separate libraries.

The original source code is the following :

```
    System.Windows.Window myObject=
        (System.Windows.Window)Activator.CreateInstance("MyLibrary", "MyLibrary.MyType")
        .Unwrap();
```

Important note :  MyType ALWAYS derives from System.Windows.Window.

I'm stuck with the following code that doesn't compile :

```
Type receptionPanelViewType = Type.GetType("MyLibrary.MyType,MyLibrary");
ConstructorInfo ctor = receptionPanelViewType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

var delegateType = typeof(Func<System.Windows.Window>).MakeGenericType(receptionPanelViewType);
var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(delegateType, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ctor));
var constructor = lambda.Compile();
System.Windows.Window receptionPanelView = constructor();
```

The error is 'constructor' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE 1** : The goal here to is to use the fastest code. Of course I would cache the compiled lambda. The type would be a parameter if this code is to be refactored in a method.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the simpler, easier to read code that actually works?

Comment: Because I need the fastest way to create those objects. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would probably work:

```
var receptionPanelView = constructor.DynamicInvoke() as System.Windows.Window;
```

Comment: Fair enough, the lambda expression, once compiled does in repeated use yield better performance that constant reuse of reflection, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Compile()` returns a simple `Delegate` type because it can return any kind of delegate. Since you know exactly what type it will be returning, you can simply cast the delegate to the right type and use it as such:

```
var constructor = (Func<System.Windows.Window>) lambda.Compile();
System.Windows.Window receptionPanelView = constructor();
```

Comment: I may be wrong, it compiles ok but throw an exception at runtime : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`1[MyLibrary.MyType]' to type 'System.Func`1[System.Windows.Window]'.